# Dropdown menu not 100% visible

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, safari

we've created a form for our client and it works on desktop.
On mobile there's a bit of an issue.
the drop down bar is only 50% visible.

[image]

This is the code for the drop down.

```html
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    id="country_code" 
    name="country_code" 
    style="border-radius:0; border:0; padding: 16px 8px 16px 8px; height:48px; background-color:#F4F4F4;" 
    required
>
    <option value="">Select country</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
</select>

<br/>
<div class="form-group">
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your problem isn't reproducible using the code you posted. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the specified height of 48px.
Try using percentage like:

```
height: 100%;
```